# Quarkus inject RequestInfo in bean

Tags: jax-rs, cdi, quarkus

I'm able to inject `RequesInfo` instances in Jaxrs resources by using the `@Context` annotation.
What I'm trying to do is to inject the same interface but in a bean that is not a Jaxrs resource. This fails with a NPE when accessing the variable.

```java
@RequestScoped
public class Service {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    public Service() {

    }

    public ResourceInfo getResourceInfo() {
        return resourceInfo;
    }
}
```

```java
@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {

    private final Service service;

    @Inject
    public GreetingResource(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello RESTEasy";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("service")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String resourceInfoService() {
        return service.getResourceInfo().getResourceClass().getName();
    }

}
```

I have looked at Jaxrs spec but I did saw any clear evidence saying that this should be supported or not. I've used this technique in other spec implementations like Payara, but in Quarkus it fails.

Comment: Injecting the `ResourceInfo` in a service feel... wrong. May I ask what the rationale behind this is?

Comment: Feels wrong from a design perspective and is wrong from a technical perspective... Usually injection of `@Context`-things is the responsibility of the JAX-RS extension (portable CDI extension in plain CDI, Quarkus extension here). The extension would inject `@Context`-things only to beans it manages, i.e. JAX-RS resources. So, noone is going ti inject a `@Context` into a non-JAX-RS bean.

Comment: If you really want to get hold of a JAX-RS `@Context`-thing from within a plain CDI bean, you can use a trick: a "holder" CDI bean, e.g. `class ResourceInfoHolder { private ResourceInfo ri; public ResourceInfo getResourceInfo() ... public void setResourceInfo(...) }`. Set the `@Context` from a JAX-RS filter and inject the holder into your plain CDI bean to get it.

Comment: ...but dont do that. If you do, your logic (i.e. CDI beans) are tightly coupled with the way your app is accessed (in this case, JAX-RS). I would rather extract any useful info from the `ResourceInfo` into the holder and use that.

Comment: I'm not so sure why this is just wrong. The `RequestScope` scope is for such use cases. The rest is just plain IoC. The service is bound to an interface that in this case is Jaxrs but could be something else entirely.
But the question is more about spec implementation. I'm just wondering if this should be supported on the framework side or not.

Comment: Should anyone want to pick up this thread again, an "elegant" use case for such an injection might be where there are outbound I/O beans which e.g. need some metadata of the request, such as a topic publisher that ought to fill the metadata of an event based on request details. In such a case it is dragging the relevant bits and pieces of the request through all of the business logic beans just so it would eventually be consumed by a publisher that I would not call elegant. Rather, the publisher bean should be able to simply access the request details, which are technically static anyway.